# dedicated windows server with apache, how to enable access to site from outside

Tags: apache-http-server

My configuration:

- Windows 2012 server
- Apache 2.4.9
- PHP 5.5.10

I can load my test page "index.html" or "index.php" 
with the browser installed at the server after typing "localhost"

I can't load the test page while accessing from external browser
after typing the IP "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

how do I allow access from anywhere to my site?

Comment: Is that xxx your external IP and do you have HTTP port 80 traffic pointed at your server?

Comment: the xxx.xxx... is my server IP. I'm connecting to the server with "remote desktop" with the same IP. How do I see if port 80 have traffic?

Comment: I assume you are using an internal IP for remote desktop. You need to use your external IP when visiting from an external site and port forward 80 from your router to your server internal IP. Have you done all this?

Comment: I don't understand something, if I'm connecting to this "Cloud" server from my home using "remote desktop" with IP. Can that IP can be internal?

Comment: Are you hosting this server yourself or are you paying a company for it? Is your remote desktop used from outside the network the server sites on?

Comment: Another thing to ask is if port 80 has been opened in the firewall on the server

Comment: I'm paying for this dedicated server and the remote desktop is outside the network the server sites on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted guys the problem was that Port 80 was blocked. It wasn't at the server itself it was at the server farm. They have firewall before the server.

So additionally to checking the sarver firewall, check if at the server farm exists other firewall (Hardware) that blocks your port 80.